# Figuring out how my /etc/ folder got deleted

Tags: linux, bash, logging, history

I was playing around with my `sendmail` configuration in the `/etc/` folder, and then, somehow, the contents of my `/etc/` folder went away, and I'm unsure of how.  From `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Nov  8 10:28:42 www sshd[25389]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user neubert
Nov  8 10:28:42 www sshd[25389]: pam_mail(sshd:session): user unknown
Nov  8 10:28:42 www sshd[25389]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): Unable to open env file: /etc/environment: No such file or directory
Nov  8 10:28:42 www sshd[25389]: pam_env(sshd:setcred): No such user!?
```

`/root/.bash_history` doesn't reveal anything, either.

I was able to recover from a backup, but I'd still like to know what happened.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Your question doesn't give enough information to provide an answer.

Here are a few possibilities though

- Your machine was comprimised and someone thought it would be fun to delete your etc directory (improbable)
- You have a script that is behaving in a way that you didn't expect (maybe it was supposed to clean something else out and crawled its way over to etc.  This would likely be something you wrote yourself.
- you made a typo when you were deleting one file in etc and ended up deleting all the files in etc.  ie `rm /etc/*`